# Agent suddenly leaves the conversation without any indication about what the error is

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assist-api

I've been doing some work with Google assistant and it works fine but sometimes the agents suddenly leaves the conversation and neither the error view nor the logs have any indications about what happened. I need a clue why this response never reached the agent (given it is sent within the 5 seconds window) and why there is no indications in the logs about what happened. Sometime my query is directed to general google search instead, which is not what I expect the user to get.

Response sent from the agent backend is below.

```
{    "expectUserResponse": true,    "expectedInputs": [
       {
           "inputPrompt": {
               "initialPrompts": [],
               "noInputPrompts": [],
               "richInitialPrompt": {
                   "items": [
                       {
                           "simpleResponse": {
                               "textToSpeech": "Here is what I found. This product is manufactured by Carroll & Meynell. The retail    price of this product is 297.93 GBP. What would you like to do?. ",
                               "displayText": "Let me see what I can find for you. Here is what I found. This product is manufactured by    Carroll & Meynell. The retail price of this product is 297.93 GBP. it    also has 230 V ac Primary Voltage Rating, ±55 V ac Secondary Voltage    Rating, 3 kVA Power Rating, 27 A Output Current and CMHT Series. What    would you like to do?. "
                           }
                       },
                       {
                           "basicCard": {
                               "title": "Carroll & Meynell, 3kVA CMHT Safety Transformer, 230V ac, 27A",
                               "image": {
                                   "url": "https://test.com/t_large/R3996140-01.jpg",
                                   "accessibilityText": "Other Images"
                               },
                               "buttons": []
                           }
                       }
                   ],
                   "suggestions": [
                       {
                           "title": "Manufacturer Info"
                       },
                       {
                           "title": "Prices and Stock"
                       },
                       {
                           "title": "More Like This"
                       },
                       {
                           "title": "Accessories"
                       },
                       {
                           "title": "Product Alternative"
                       },
                       {
                           "title": "Warranty Info"
                       },
                       {
                           "title": "Technical Details"
                       },
                       {
                           "title": "Other Options"
                       }
                   ]
               }
           },
           "possibleIntents": [
               {
                   "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT"
               }
           ]
       }    
    ] 
}
```

Comment: Is this happening on your phone? In the web simulator?

Comment: @NickFelker This issue is with the simulator

Comment: @NickFelker it is happening with both actually. but my trial was with the simulator. All I am looking for is a clue in the logs to see what is going on and subsequently fix my response if it has any issues

Comment: @NickFelker this is really annoying as hell, I am getting the agent quits the conversation more frequently without any indication what the error is. please help.

Comment: Okay can you share the project with my email fleker@google.com and I'll see if I can reproduce your issue?

Answer (score -1):

@NickFelker Same thing is happening with me as well both on simulator and phone. The actions-on-google is really bad and unstructed and on top of that issues like these - I have made the same things work with custom payload for Facebook Messenger. I am really thinking about not touching actions-on-google for a while because its unstable like hell.